# Dell Inspiron 1746 screen goes crazy

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1746 with Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, 4GB RAM, Intel HD graphics. The problem is after an hour or few the screen goes crazy with a noise and colored lines and then the computer freezes. This happens when i play games on Facebook or installed games, not specifically when I play games, but usually after the computer has been on for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is overheating. You can try cleaning the computer by using a vacuum cleaner on all openings on the laptop body to get any dust that has built up inside blocking the airflow.

Comment: I don't have a vacuum cleaner :(

Comment: *Don't* use a vacuum cleaner! Use a can of compressed air instead.

Answer (score 0):

If colored lines happen, that could be your graphic's card problem. You might need to upgrade your graphic's card.
But do try cleaning your laptop body first. If this situation happens a lot, only cleaning is not gonna get you out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem on my Dell Latitude E5420 laptop... with crazy lines, dots, noise flashing all over the screen as the system freezes. Problem was caused by changing RAM however. Changing it back stopped it from happening.